# 298 _IsPressed or HotKeySet call in a service not working

Tags: vba, autoit

I am confuse why any form of keyboard press doesn't work in a service,  Can anyone help me spot where I am doing wrong?

```
HotKeySet("^+!d", "Func1") ;crl-Shift-Alt-d
...
While $ServiceRunning

   ;Or --->  If _IsPressed('76') Then
               Func1()  
   Sleep(1000)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure, but I assume, that if your script is really running as service, it's using another account (e.g. Local System) than the user actually being logged in. It shouldn't be possible for a service / process of user x's session to get keys (or even other information) of user y's session.

You could try to run the services with the same account as the user of which you try to get the keys or just let the service start a process for the corresponding user session which collects the keys.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Torsten. I got it. I think I should study impersonation where the service impersonate on a task using the context of another user.